# Is it necessary to Remove viewController as observer during an edit in an iCloud app?

Tags: icloud, nsnotification

Take the example of two iOS device running the same app that has iCloud support.
The app has CoreData and is "Library" style, not a multiple document
style app.

User A is adding an object using the interface and during this addition
user B saves the MOC with a new object on the other device. A notification on user A's device will cause the addition of user B's object before user A is done adding his object. This could cause the number of fetchedObjects to change during the [tableView reloadData] on A's device .. and error condition I believe.

Do I need to remove the viewController as an observer whenever the user is editing the 
MOC? If so does iCloud "sense" this and resend the "missed" notifications once the mentioned
viewController is re-added as an observer? I have been unable to find a discussion of this.

Thanks very much for reading. Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to this iCloud question and more found at: http://mentalfaculty.tumblr.com/archive
Look for "Under the Sheets with iCloud and CoreData"